# CORTEX M4: Confusion on BX and BLX instruction and bit(0) of LR

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

My understanding is that for the cortex M4, the address register for BX and BLX must have bit(0) set to 1. I am confused how this works with regards to the BLX instruction, does the address inserted into the LR register after execution BLX instruction have bit(0) set to 1? Do I need to manually change it to 1 prior to executing a return using the BX instruction?

The other option is to use: MOV PC, LR but it seems like that is defeating the purpose of the branch instructions.

Comment: Who is the vendor for your Cortex-M4 based microcontroller?

Comment: TI, I am using the Launchpad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does the address inserted into the LR register after execution BLX instruction have bit(0) set to 1?

Yes.

The BLX instruction sets bit(0) of LR to 0 if the CPU was running in ARM mode before the jump and to 1 if the CPU was running in Thumb mode.

Because the Cortex M4 only supports the Thumb instruction mode (and not the ARM mode) bit(0) will always be set to 1 by BLX.

> The other option is to use: MOV PC, LR but it seems like that is defeating the purpose of the branch instructions.

On the old ARM CPUs that did not have Thumb mode the `MOV PC,LR` instruction was the "official" return instruction.

The disadvantage is that you cannot return to a Thumb function from an ARM function and vice versa.

On a CPU that does only support Thumb mode you may also use that instruction.

Comment: Thank you. NONE of the documents on the ARM website said that the LR return address saved the current instruction execution mode of the of the processor. They only said that the address was saved. Seems like a glaring oversight.

Comment: It is documented elsewhere as it is no specific to the LR. Jumps to Thumb instructions always jump to an odd address (and likewise jumps to ARM instructions always jump to even addresses).

Comment: @FourierFlux Unfortunately the ARM web site doesn't have the real documentation. For details like what instructions actually do you need one of the ARM Architecture Reference Manuals, which are only available to "registered ARM customers".

Comment: @RossRidge On the ARM website, the architecture manual is only available for registered customers. However, it can be downloaded from the [Intel web site](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/literature/third-party/ddi0100e_arm_arm.pdf), for example, without a registration.

Comment: @FourierFlux from the printed on paper architectural reference manuals through to the versions that were first digitally available to the present all indicate the LR lsbit contains the mode.  For example LR = (address of next instruction) | 1  and LR = PC<31:1> : ‘1’;